# Is it natural and correct to say "do a particular amount of money on something" meaning to pay or receive money for a service?

Tags: prepositions, phrases

Is it natural and correct to say *do a particular amount of money on something* meaning to pay or receive money for a service? For example:

The most I can **do on** that car is 1000 dollars.

By that I mean the most can sell the car for is 1000 dollars.

If it's not natural, would you please tell if it is more natural to swap *on* out for *for* there?

Answer (score 1):

When in the context of a purchase, I would definitely agree with you that swapping out the "on" for "for" would sound more natural and correct.

> The most I can do **for** that car is 1000 dollars.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would you tell me if "on" would work if it was me who were going to buy the car.

Comment: This *is* the sentence that you would use if you were buying the car: saying "The most I can for that car is 1000 dollars." is the same as saying "The most I am willing to pay for that car is 1000 dollars."

Comment: Sorry! I made a mistake! Would you please tell me if it is correct to use "on" instead of "for" if I were the one selling the car?